# Inno Setup - How to execute MSI between 32 and 64 architectures

Tags: inno-setup

im trying to run 2 msi files for 32 and 64 bits from a third party and i am having a little trouble with the msi for 32bits windows architectures. 
It seems the program extracts quite well the file but it doesn´t execute the installer. In the other hand for 64bits windows architectures the installer works. I don´t know where is the problem. Is there anything wrong with my code that im not seeing?Thank you!

```
[Setup]
...
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Files]
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
Source: "filex64.msi"; DestName: "file.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "filex32.msi"; DestName: "file.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode;
Source: "manual.pdf"; DestDir: "{userdesktop}"; DestName: "Manual.pdf"

[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/package ""{app}\file.msi"" /qn /norestart /passive"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "A instalar software {#MyAppVersion}"; 
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Manual.pdf"; Flags: postinstall;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out.

Flags

**32bit**

Causes the {sys} constant to map to the 32-bit System directory when used in the Filename and WorkingDir parameters. This is the default behavior in a 32-bit mode install.

This flag cannot be combined with the shellexec flag.

**64bit**

Causes the {sys} constant to map to the 64-bit System directory when used in the Filename and WorkingDir parameters. This is the default behavior in a 64-bit mode install.

This flag can only be used when Setup is running on 64-bit Windows, otherwise an error will occur. On an installation supporting both 32- and 64-bit architectures, it is possible to avoid the error by adding a Check: IsWin64 parameter, which will cause the entry to be silently skipped when running on 32-bit Windows.

This flag cannot be combined with the shellexec flag.

Source:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64

Based on this, i changed my script ir order to pinpoint correctly the "msiexec.exe" file for both architectures. Thank you guys!

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/package    ""{userdesktop}\Classic_Client_{#MyAppVersion}_64.msi"" /qn /norestart /passive"; Flags: 64bit skipifdoesntexist waituntilterminated; Check:IsWin64; StatusMsg: "A instalar Classic Client {#MyAppVersion} - 64bit"; 
Filename: "{sys}\msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/package  ""{userdesktop}\Classic_Client_{#MyAppVersion}_32.msi"" /qn /norestart /passive"; Flags:   32bit skipifdoesntexist waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "A instalar Classic Client   {#MyAppVersion} - 32bit";
```

Answer (score 1):

the {sys} constant is the issue.

> {sys} The system's System32 directory. For example: If you used
>   {sys}\CTL3D32.DLL on an entry and the system's Windows System
>   directory is "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM", Setup or Uninstall will translate it
>   to "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\CTL3D32.DLL".
>
> On 64-bit Windows, by default, the System32 path returned by this
>   constant maps to the directory containing 32-bit system files, just
>   like on 32-bit Windows. (This can be overridden by enabling 64-bit
>   mode.)

Comment: If the `msiexec.exe` resides only in the 32-bit system folder then yes, the `{sys}` constant is the issue since OP used the 64-bit mode which resolves the `{sys}` constant to the 64-bit system folder. However, it would be great to mention what to do...

Comment: It make sense. With the option "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64" the program runs great in x64 but not in x32 because probably it is pointing to: C:\Windows\SysWow64\ witch doesnt exist in x32.

If i disable "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64" it doesnt work for both. I assume it translate to c:\windows\system\

What is the best course of action? Do i need to use the code section for this?